# Data Validation formula with Nested Substitute replacing "/" and "&" characters

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I am trying to figure out why this formula is not working in my data validation field. I am using Excel 2010 and I have a large number of named ranges with a mixture of characters in a drop down list in Column c, in column d I have a dependent drop down list that currently works for some, but not all of the options listed in column C. 
An example of one of the options in Column c is "10-40 Lby W" - The current formula works for that:

```
=INDIRECT(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE($C13," ","_"),"-","_"))
```

But it won't work with this example "2/3-44K ARV" so I wrote it to look like below:

```
=INDIRECT(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE($C13," ","_"),"-","_"),"/","_"),"&","_"))
```

However for reasons unbeknowst to me, that one does not work. When I put it into a cell and try to evaluate the formula it says "The Cell currently being evaluated contains a constant". I get the generic error message "The formula you typed contains an error." when I insert the second formula in the data validation form. Usually that means a syntax error, but I am wondering if the addition of the / and & characters are the problem. Any ideas?

Comment: Indirect references the choice made in the dropdown list in column C. Refers the dropdown list in column d to the appropriate named range.

Comment: Is period here "`$C13.`" a typo? Seems to me that it should be a comma.

Answer (score 1):

It seems it is a syntax error.

```
=INDIRECT(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE($C13." ","_"),"-","_"),"/","_"),"&","_"))
```

Should be:

```
=INDIRECT(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE($C13," ","_"),"-","_"),"/","_"),"&","_"))
```

Comment: Not sure if it was the period, or another piece of syntax but it is working correctly now.

Comment: @pnuts I'm not sure what you are talking about. I don't see that interaction in this posting other than my own comment to the same effect. Can you clarify what answer from Wooz you are referencing?